# Firefox web app: Control duration of load screen

Tags: web-applications, usability, gecko, firefox-os

I test installed a web app on an Android device with Firefox Aurora.
What the user sees during startup:

1. Load screen 1: App's icon plus loader animation (green circle).
2. Load screen 2: App's own load screen (spinner on black background), indicating
   initialization.
3. The app, ready to use.

Is it possible to get rid of the second load screen?

In other words: Can I somehow control how long the first load screen appears?

*Note*: Naturally, I do not want to entirely get rid of the app's own load screen. It is
necessary on normal browsers, since otherwise users may see the app in an uninitialized state.

Comment: Do you have a test url or manifest file link?

Comment: Early preview: [ROTOGAMEsq install page](http://sq.rotogame.com/install-webapp)

Comment: [manifest.webapp](http://sq.rotogame.com/manifest.webapp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to control the duration or content of the first load screen. A [bug has been filed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=805845), however, and you can follow any further progress there.

You'll have to work around this problem in the short term, and two solutions that have been proposed are:

- Make your second load screen look like your app itself even though it won't be responsive (eg: screenshot of your app's last state). This trick is widely used in mobile apps.
- Make your second load screen look like the first load screen. The background color should always be predictable, if not, please file a bug!

Comment: Thanks, Anant, for clarification. However, I don't like the proposal in the bug report, and so I proposed [an alternative](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=805889). The alternative is 1. always consistent, and 2. very easy to implement for app developers.